# C# Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, null

I have the following code:

```
public void SetUser(User user)
{
   string streetNumber = "";

   if (user.Address.StreetNo != null)
      streetNumber = user.Address.StreetNo.ToString();
   else
     streetNumber = "";
}
```

I get the ever popular

```
Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

issue.

Comment: First check if user is not null then user.Address not null and only then StreeNo...

Comment: where does the stacktrace point you to? are you sure that "user" will not be null? Sorry but I can't tell from your code. It might be the Address of the user is null it might be the StreeetNo - it might be almost everything in there

Comment: Thanks for the comments guys, they were write and go along with the answer curt has provided. The Stack did show the user exsisted but I wasn't doing the check.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
public void SetUser(User user)
{
   string streetNumber = "";

   if (user != null && user.Address != null && user.Address.StreetNo != null) {
      streetNumber = user.Address.StreetNo.ToString();
   }
}
```

Taking into account @CKoenig's suggestion, the following throws an exception if the `user` or `user.Address` are `null`:

```
public void SetUser(User user)
{

   if (user == null) {
       throw new System.ArgumentNullException("user", "user cannot be null");
   }

   if (user.Address == null) {
       throw new System.ArgumentNullException("Address", "Address cannot be null");
   }
   
   string streetNumber = "";

   if (user.Address.StreetNo != null) {
      streetNumber = user.Address.StreetNo.ToString();
   }
}
```

Comment: I would recommend throwing if either is null - the method is named "SetUser" if it can't because there is nothing to set it should not pretent to do.

Comment: The method name has to be wrong.  It doesn't do anything like the method body describes.

Comment: @Inuyasha OP could have simplified their method leaving only this part which seems to be throwing an exception

Comment: @Curt you are correct I didn't want to give to much of the code away. :)

Comment: @CKoenig I have other values not all values are required streetNumber is not a required value so if it is null I would like to return nothing.

Comment: @Curt Thanks buddy accepted because quickest response with code that solves issue.

Comment: @Curt: I suggest using `ArgumentNullException` at least for the case where `user` is null, since this is a more specific exception type.

Comment: @Curt  : you still throwing an exception when user != null, does this make any sense?

Comment: @Curt: now looks much better ;)

Comment: Thanks guys, making my my coding practices better is much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Either `user` is null, or `user.Address` is null.  You need to test them too.

Comment: No, you missed this clause: `if (user.Address.StreetNo != null)`.  He is already checking if `user.Address.StreetNo` is null.  The problem is that this test itself will throw the exception if either of `user` or `user.Address` are null.

Comment: so sorry- you are right ... better think first ... but alas then there will be 10 answers ;)

Comment: Thanks guys +1 because you were right accepted curts because he provided code with answer.

Answer (score 2):

```
public void SetUser(User user) 
{    
   string streetNumber = String.Empty;     

   if (user!= null 
       && user.Address != null 
       && user.Address.StreetNo != null)       
   {
         streetNumber = user.Address.StreetNo.ToString();    
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Check your stacktrace and:

- user
- user.Address
- user.Address.StreetNo

with an if ... == null then ...

Answer (score 1):

```
if (user != null
    && user.Address != null
    && user.Address.StreetNo != null)
{
    // ...
}
```